# iOS 8 Autolayout frame animation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios8, xcode6

No auto layout is being used in the view. The below code used to work just fine for my app iOS7. It animated the frames of a few IBOutlet objects upward. However, now it animates as expected but then snaps back immidiately upon completion of the animation.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(animated) ? 1.0 : 0.0 animations:^{
        numberEntry.alpha = 0.0;
        instrTextOne.alpha = 0.0;
        numberEntry.frame = CGRectOffset(numberEntry.frame, 0, -100);
        instrTextTwo.alpha = 1.0;
        instrTextTwo.frame = CGRectOffset(instrTextTwo.frame, 0, -100);
        phoneEntryBg.alpha = 0.0;
        phoneEntryBg.frame = CGRectOffset(phoneEntryBg.frame, 0, -100);
        codeEntryBg.frame = CGRectOffset(codeEntryBg.frame, 0, -100);
        codeEntryBg.alpha = 1.0;
        seperator.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        numberEntry.text = @"";
        numberEntry.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
```

Can anybody advise me as to what I might be doing wrong? Is there a better practice here?

Comment: Are you saying you're using autolayout for some views and not others? That seems likely to cause problems -- it doesn't play nicely with programmatic manipulation of views.

Comment: No I am using no autolayout! Client did not want or care about iPhone 4 compatibility (and this was back when it was only iPhone 4 and 5).